# Can an entry in one cell change the decimal places for an entire column in Excel?

Tags: excel

I have made a calculator for dosing chemicals to a swimming pool. You input say 15,000 gallons and ask it how much chlorine is needed for 2 ppm. It gives the answer in oz and lbs to 2 decimal places. But when the gallons are small like 350 gallons, 2 decimal places is not enough. Can this be automated so that when the gallons entered are less than 1,000 it shows 3 or 4 decimal places in a column? Or when it is more than 1,000 gallons it shows 2 decimal places? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the input, try the following formula (replace `A1/55555` to your actual input reference - 15,000 gallons in your example): `=ROUND(A1/55555,IF(A1>1000,2,4))`

Thus, if input, i.e. A1, matches your requirements - the result is rounded to definite amount of decimal places. Hope that was helpful)

Sample result:

```
Input   Result
800     0,0144
1500    0,03
```